# How to exit out of Makefile command when variable definition fails?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Considering this contrived example:

```
FOO_VALUE := $(shell foo_command)

foo:
    if [ -z $(FOO_VALUE) ]; then echo "missing value" && exit 1; fi
```

If `foo_command` isn't installed, the variable definition raises an error. But to my surprise, the `make foo` command continues to run:

```
$ make foo
make: foo_command: Command not found
if [ -z  ]; then echo "missing value" && exit 1; fi
missing value
make: *** [foo] Error 1
```

In the interest of failing early, I'd rather that it exit when `$(shell foo_command)` fails. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.  The `shell` function never causes make to exit, if it fails.  This is probably what 90% of users want.

If you have GNU Make 4.2 or better you can use the `.SHELLSTATUS` variable to obtain the status of the immediately-preceding `$(shell ...)` function:

```
FOO_VALUE := $(shell foo_command)
$(if $(filter-out 0,$(.SHELLSTATUS)),$(error Failed))
```

but more portable, and arguably better anyway, is to just test the value if that's what you want:

```
FOO_VALUE := $(shell foo_command)
$(if $(FOO_VALUE),,$(error Failed))
```

Comment: Just to note that by "more portable" I mean "more portable to older versions of GNU Make"; obviously none of this is portable to other implementations of make.